# system freeze when surfing with firefox and 4 or more tabs open

Tags: firefox, freeze

It mostly occurs when firefox is used with 4 or more tabs open. The only way out is hard restart
Laptop: Dell 3180 single-boot
OS:     Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Hi.Please can you [edit] your question and add details like what was you doing when crash occured, check system monitor for unusual activity, how much RAM do you have, on which version of Firefox is that occuring.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM FIXED
After disabling few addons (mostly adblockers) on firefox the problem seem to have been solved.

thanks